# Solution consisting scheme (?)

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to prove that this implicit and multisteps scheme is consistent or not:
$$y_{k+1}=\frac{1}{8}[9y_k-y_{k-2}+3hf(x_{k+1},y_{k+1})+6hf(x_k,y_k)-3hf(x_{k-1},y_{
k-1}) ]$$

but I'm a little lost because this is a multistep method and I have no light to be displayed in this case.

$\textbf{Edit:}$

The scheme is for compute a solution of a initial value problem:

$$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)) \ \ \ x\in [a,b]$$
$$y(a)=\alpha$$

And one method is consistent if the global truncation error tends to zero as $h$ (step size) tends to zero.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: what $f(x,y)$ means? any function?what is $h$?

Comment: @chenbai, $f$ is a function that satisfies the necessary conditions for applying the method, and $h$ is the step size.